# Kubernetes Cronjob Error not a native sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-dashboard

I have a kubernetes v1.25 and i cant show the details of my cronjobs anymore on all of my namespace of my kubernetes dashboard.
FYI, it works in command kubectl line i can list my cronjobs and access.
Dashboard version used 2.7.0

On my project i modified the api version to the one recommended :
apiVersion: 'batch/v1'
kind: 'CronJob'

When i check the logs of my kubernetes dashboard pod, i can see that every time i try to check the details of my cronjob on a namespace through graphical dashboard, an error log pop "There was an error during transformation to sidecar selector: Resource "cronjob" is not a native sidecar resource type or is not supported".

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: Your problem seems to refer to an old Dashboard bug fixed some time ago.

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/4145 ;

Could you share the Dashboard Pod logs?

Comment: @knbch is your issue resolved revert back if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug where kubernetes dashboard is using API version batchV1beta1 for cronjobs which has been removed in kuberentes version 1.25.

I've created a fixed version based on kuberentes dashboard version v2.7.0. I've published it on docker hub: `beffe/kubernetes-dashboard:v2.7.0-fix-cj-2`

You can find the code changes here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/compare/master...beffe123:kubernetes-dashboard:v2.7.0-fixes

Answer (score 0):

There might be two reasons for this issue to occur.

1. Like `glv` said the primary reason will be version mismatch and the bug
   related to that particular dashboard version. Upgrade your dashboard to
   the latest supported version or follow the steps provided by `glv`, these
   will help you in resolving the issue.
2. The second issue is related to the permissions. Check whether you have
   provided necessary permissions to the kubernetes dashboard service
   account or RBAC role, assign the necessary permissions if not available
   it will help you in resolving these issues.

Go through the logs related to kube-dashboard pods which will provide further details that will help you in diagnosing the issue more clearly. Hope this will help you

Comment: @knbch is your issue resolved revert back if you need any additional information.